# Unable to use PhantomJS driver with Firefox profile in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver, phantomjs

I try to use a PhantomJS driver for my Selenium tests but I don't succeed to recover my Firefox profile to avoid me login in the website.
This is my code :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Stackoverflow {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        baseUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStackoverflow() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how to set PhantomJS driver ?

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to use a firefox profile with PhantomJS because you're trying to use a firefox profile with PhantomJS... PhantomJS is not firefox, how did you think that was going to work.

Comment: I know it's impossible of course, but I ask if there is a solution with using firefox profile or other.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set the path of the phantomjs driver, Use this and let me know if you facing any issue:

```
File file = new File("E:\\software and tools\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");               
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

OR

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "E:\\software and tools\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");    
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```